# Antiderivative of Heaviside function with absolute-value-argument

Tags: integration, step-function

I'm looking to calculate the antiderivative of $$\Theta (R-|x|),$$where $\Theta$ denotes the Heaviside step function and $R$ is a given constant. On Wikipedia it is given that $\int_{-\infty}^x \Theta(t) \mathrm{d} t=x\Theta(x)$, however, here the argument is a bit more involved. Any comments or answers on how to go about this problem are appreciated.

Comment: Hmm. From a naive standpoint and a first glimpse, it seems like it's similar to [this](https://functions.wolfram.com/IntegerFunctions/Floor/21/01/01/). I remember proving the equation in that link by differentiating the floor function (where $z$ isn't an integer), getting $0$, and integrating both sides. These are just my thoughts though.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. You didn’t by any chance write down that proof somewhere?

Comment: I did, actually. I got $\frac{d}{dx}\lfloor{x\rfloor} = 0$, then $\int \frac{d}{dx} \lfloor{x\rfloor}dx = \int 0dx$, then $\lfloor{x\rfloor} = 0 + C$, then $\int \lfloor{x\rfloor} dx = \int Cdx = Cx + D = \lfloor{x\rfloor}x + D$ for some constants $C$ and $D$. I'm not sure how I feel about applying the indefinite integral on both sides, but I used this same result (but with the interval of integration not having a jump discontinuity) in an induction proof and it worked out.

Answer (score 1):

If $R\le0$, then the antiderivative is just some constant $C$.

If $R>0$, then, by inspection, the antiderivative is $$(R+x)\theta(R-|x|)+2R\theta(x-R)+C.$$

If we take the derivative of the latter w.r.t. $x$, we find $$\theta(R-|x|)-2R\delta(R-x)\theta(x)+2R\delta(x-R)+(R+x)\delta(R+x)\theta(-x) + R\delta(x)-R\delta(-x) \\ =\theta(R-|x|).$$

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Why is the antiderivative just a constant when $R\leq 0$? Also, in taking the derivative of the expression you find for $R>0$, could you list all identities you use? For example, what is the derivative of $\theta (R-|x|)$?